# Customize Login Process of Wordpress

Tags: php, authentication, wordpress

I want to create a wordpress plugin to have the following process

Step 1: the user will enter the username and password then press on Login button.

Step 2: the system will check the username and password if available in Local DB.

Step 3: if user is Available in Local DB , Login will proceed successfully.

Step 4: in case the user is not in Local DB, the system will check the username and password via External Web Service.

Step 5: the Web serivce will reply back with the user information if available.

Step 6: if the user information is available, the system will create a new user in Local DB with the user information, hence the next login will process the login successfully.

Step 7: if the user information is not available, the system will redirect the user to some error message page.

After alot of search I could not know from where to start, should I create the plugin by my self, or just modify any login plugin available on the internet, or should I just modify directly on wp-login.php

If there are some resources I should read, or any tutorials you guys suggest, please provide it to me.

Answer (score 1):

I would advise you to play with the filter "authenticate" applied in function ["wp_authenticate"](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/100e737eb05d01bcb876367c724f0a3ae8976c80/wp-includes/pluggable.php#L517).
You might need to remove the filter ["wp_authenticate_username_password"](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/d56f4a30b953b99402e37cb4d97cac8189aabb63/wp-includes/default-filters.php#L301) and create your own authentication function, that will follow closely [the default one](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/d56f4a30b953b99402e37cb4d97cac8189aabb63/wp-includes/user.php#L114).